# How to put the data taken from google custom search API to checkbox list

Tags: html, checkbox, javascript

I have a code which takes data from google custom search API, There is no wrong with the custom search API part, it retrieves data without any error

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
    var pageName = new Array();
    var pageLink = new Array();
    var pageDetails = new Array();

      function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
       var item = response.items[i];

        pageName[i] = item.title;
        pageLink[i] = item.link;
        pageDetails[i] = item.htmlSnippet;

      }
    }

    // Some codes

    var search_query = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=XXXXXXXXX&q='+query+'&start=1&callback=hndlr';
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = search_query;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s); 
    </script>     
  </body>
</html>
```

**Required data are saved in the pageName, pageLink and pageDetails arrays**.
Now I want display them with chechboxes and allow user to select them.
I need to take the links of the selected sites(pageLink variable) and pass it to anothe file using POST method
I tried using bellow code just before end of the body tag()

```
<form action="b.php" method="post">
<script>
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
document.write("<input type='checkbox' name='formDoor[]' id='"+j+"' value= '' />"+pageName[j]+"<br />"); 
document.getElementById(j).value = pageLink[j]; 
}
</script>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But in the other file, it says variables are undefined. seems like variables doesn't pass to the 'b.php' file

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code for adding checkboxes would likely be executed before the search result arrives (i.e.: before `hndlr` is executed), so all arrays are still empty. The solution would be to move the checkbox creation code into the `hndlr` function.

Here's the fixed page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <form id="bform" action="b.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
    var pageName = new Array();
    var pageLink = new Array();
    var pageDetails = new Array();

    function hndlr(response) {
      var f=document.getElementById('bform'), prev=f.children[0];
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var ele, item = response.items[i];

        pageName[i] = item.title;
        pageLink[i] = item.link;
        pageDetails[i] = item.htmlSnippet;

        ele = document.createElement('BR');
        f.insertBefore(ele, prev);
        prev = ele;

        ele = document.createTextNode(pageName[i]);
        f.insertBefore(ele, prev);
        prev = ele;

        ele = document.createElement('INPUT');
        ele.type = 'checkbox';
        ele.name = 'formDoor[]';
        ele.id = i;
        ele.value = encodeURI(pageLink[i]);
        f.insertBefore(ele, prev);
        prev = ele;
      }
    }

    // Some codes

    var search_query = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=XXXXXXXXX&q='+query+'&start=1&callback=hndlr';
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = search_query;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s); 
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```